# Determining when to scale up my AWS RDS database?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm building a web service, consisting of many different components, all of which could conceivably be bottlenecks. I'm currently trying to figure out what metrics I should be looking for, when deciding whether or not my database (on AWS RDS) is the bottleneck in the chain.

Looking at AWS Cloudwatch, I see a number of RDS metrics given. Full list:

1. CPUCreditBalance
2. CPUCreditUsage
3. CPUUtilization
4. DatabaseConnections
5. DiskQueueDepth
6. FreeStorageSpace
7. FreeableMemory
8. NetworkReceiveThroughput
9. NetworkTransmitThroughput
10. ReadIOPS
11. ReadLatency
12. ReadThroughput
13. SwapUsage
14. WriteIOPS
15. WriteLatency
16. WriteThroughput

The key metrics that I think I should be paying attention to:

1. Read/Write Latency
2. CPU-Utilization
3. Freeable Memory

With the latency metrics, I'm thinking that I should set up alerts if it exceeds >300ms (for fast website responsiveness), though I recognize that this is very much workload dependent.

With the CPU/memory-util, I have no idea what numbers to set these to. I'm thinking I should set an alert for 75% CPU-utilization, and 75% drop in Freeable Memory.

Am I on the right track with the metrics I've shortlisted above, and the thresholds I have guessed? Are there any other metrics I should be paying attention to?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is totally dependent on your application. Some applications will require more CPU, some will need more RAM. There is no definitive answer.

The best thing is to **monitor your database** (with the metrics you list above). Then, when performance is below desired, take a look at **which metrics are showing problems**. These should be the first ones you track for scaling your database.

The key idea that **if your customers are experiencing problems, it should be appearing in your metrics somewhere**. If this isn't the case, then you're not collecting sufficient metrics.

Comment: John, thank you for posting. However, your reply doesn't really help me in any way. If my customers are experiencing problems, it could also be a problem with heroku, with the number/size of web dynos I have, or the front end client itself. 

With regard to monitoring the database and metrics, what exactly would I be looking for, and what is considered "showing problems"? 

If my CPU-util hits 25%, does that mean performance will be degraded, or is it just fine? What about 50%? 75%? At what CPU utilization will database performance be hindered? Same goes for the other metrics

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track - especially with the latency metrics; for a typical application with database back-end, the read/write latency is going to be what the user notices most if it degrades. Sure the memory or cpu usage may spike, but does any user care? No, not unless it then causes the latency to go up.

I'd start with the metrics you listed as the low-hanging fruit and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Are you using prometheus? Did you set up some kind of alert rules to alert you when the RDS CPU is below 70% for example or are you manually monitoring this on the AWS Cloudwatch?  I'm trying to write some specific alerting rules for my RDS CPU utilisation and freeable memory and I'm having a tough time doing that